# I need descriptive statistics for donation information (mean, percent over a certain amount) sorted by a categorical value (Neighborhood)

Tags: r

I have this code so far that gets me everything I need from all donors. Making a new dataframe for each neighborhood isn't really an option since there are 475 of them

```
mean(data$AMOUNT < 100)
sum(data$AMOUNT < 100)
mean(data$AMOUNT > 100)
sum(data$AMOUNT > 100)
mean(data$AMOUNT == 100)
sum(data$AMOUNT == 100)
mean(data$AMOUNT == 1500)
mean(data$AMOUNT == 320)
mean(data$AMOUNT == 175)
mean(data$AMOUNT)
median(data$AMOUNT)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that using the `tidyverse` would be helpful for you (really you just need `dplyr` for this, but might as well).

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
data %>% group_by(neighborhood) %>% 
  summarize(und100=mean(AMOUNT<100),sumund100=sum(AMOUNT<100), etc...)
```

Comment: mean(data$AMOUNT == 1500) gives me the percentage of donations that were that exact amount

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you're trying to get. What I wrote now should give you that.

Comment: Thank you! I figured dplyr would help but I'm so out of practice. Should've known group_by would be what I needed.